# How can show login user profile pic using express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my profile pic model in create reference of two tables user and employee. I am using monogo db. I want to display the profile pic which user/employee upload. Pic uploaded successfully but not shown. It showing the error when i redirect to page.

```
     Cannot read property 'profileImg' of undefined
```

the error of profileImg is not occur in route.js. It show the profileImg error in ejs file
i want to display the latest upload pic on screen

profilePicModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Users = require("./authUserModel");
const Employee = require("./employeeModel");
const Schema  = mongoose.Schema
const profilePic = new Schema({
    userId:{
       type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ,
       ref:Users || Employee,
    },

    profileImg:{
       type: String
    }
})
profile = mongoose.model('Profile', profilePic)
module.exports = profile
```

route.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')
const profilePic = require('../../models/profileImgModel')

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    req.isLogged = true
    return next();
}
else{
    req.isLogged = false
    return next()
}
}

router.get('/profilePic', isLoggedIn ,((req, res) => {
     res.render('profilePic', {user:req.user , isLoggedIn: req.isLogged}) 
}))

router.post('/profilePic',upload,  function (req, res, next){
    let user = req.user
    let pic = profilePic({
        userId: user,
        profileImg: req.file.filename
    })
    pic.save()
      .then((result)=>console.log(result))
      .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    res.redirect('/customerMenu', 200)
})

module.exports = router
```

profile.ejs

```
<!Doctype Html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <title>Upload pic</title>
</head>
<body>
<% if( isLoggedIn){%>
   <img src="./public/uploads/<%= isLoggedIn.user.profileImg  %>" alt="profile pic">
<%}%>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profilePic">

     <label>Upload Pic</label>
     <input type="file" name="file">
     <button type="submit">upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add new profilePic({}) in route.js . You forgot new keyword

Comment: my pic upload successfully i just want to display profile pic. the error of profileImg is not occur in route.js. It show the profileImg error in ejs file

Comment: is there a `user` attribute inside `isLoggedIn`? In the `ejs` try `user.profileImg` instead of `isLoggedIn.user.profileImg`

Comment: i defined the isLoggedIn function but in function there is not attribute user

Comment: even i already try user.profileImg but nothing show

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to create a new object from your constructor

```
const profileImgModel = require('../../models/profileImgModel')   
const profilePic = new profileImgModel()
```

and then update the entry

```
const filter = { userId: user };
const update = { profileImg: req.file.filename }
let doc = await profilePic.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)
```

Comment: when i upload pic it successfully save in db. I want to display that profile pic. The error of profileImg is not occur in route.js. It show the profileImg error in ejs file

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read property 'profileImg' of undefined

In your `ejs` you have accessed the `profileImg` from `isLoggedIn.user`. According to the error, `user` is **undefined**.

```
router.get('/profilePic', isLoggedIn ,((req, res) => {
     res.render('profilePic', {user:req.user , isLoggedIn: req.isLogged}) 
}))
```

In the above code, you have defined `user` and `isLoggedIn`. But seems like you have missed the part that you have to **retrieve the image data from the database**.

You can use mongoose `findOne` like below:

```
router.get('/profilePic', isLoggedIn ,((req, res) => {
     profilePic.findOne({_id:<USER_ID>}, (err, imgData) => { //change <USER_ID> appropiately
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send('An error occurred', err);
        }
        else {
            res.render('profilePic', {user:req.user , isLoggedIn: req.isLogged, image: imgData.profileImg});
        }
    }); 
}))
```

Now you can use `image` in your `ejs`!

Comment: it showing the error at line {user:req.user , isLoggedIn: req.isLogged, image: imgData.profileImg});
        }
               Cannot read property 'profileImg' of null

Comment: in ejs i use user.image